# Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues are all $1$ or $-1$. show that $A^{-1}=A$

Tags: linear-algebra

## hey, I have this problem to solve but I don't know how to do it.

I think I should put $2$ matrices with eigenvalues equal to $1$ but I don't know exactly how to write it. can you solve it please?
I have tried to do determinants but haven't got any solutions

1. $A$ is diagonalizable.
2. eigenvalues are all $1$ or $-1$.
3. show that $A^{-1} = A$

Comment: what is $a$ in your title ?

Comment: He meant to write $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't know how to answer a question, just start writing the meaning of each point and then think of what you can do to answer the question.

(1) $A$ is diagonalizable. This means that $A$ can be written as:
               $$A=PDP^{-1}$$
    where $P$ is the matrix containing the eigenvectors and $D$ is the diagonal matrix 
    containing the eigenvalues.

(2) Eigenvalues are all 1 or −1. This implies $D^2=I$, so
$$A^2=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})=PD(P^{-1}P)DP^{-1}=PD(I)DP^{-1}=P(DD)P^{-1}=P(I)P^{-1}=PP^{-1}=I.$$

(3) Show that $A^{−1}=A$. Since $I=A^2$ then multiplying both sides by the inverse of $A$ gives the required result,
$$A^{-1}=A^{-1}A^2=(A^{-1}A)A=A.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a non-singular matrix $P$ such that

$P^{-1}AP = D,  \tag 1$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix the diagonal entries of which are the eigenvalues of $A$; thus each entry $d_{ii}$  on the diagonal of $D$ satisfies

$d_{ii} = \pm 1; \tag 2$

as such, the diagonal entries of $D^2$ are

$d_{ii}^2 = 1, \tag 3$

and all the non-diagonal entries of $D^2$ are zero; thus

$D^2 = I, \tag 4$

the identity matrix.  Then from (1),

$P^{-1}A^2P = P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP = D^2 = I; \tag 5$

it now follows that

$A^2 = PIP^{-1} = I. \tag 6$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Under your assumptions, there exist $V$ and diagonal $D$ with diagonal $(d_i)_{i=1}^n$ and $d_i = \pm 1$ such that $A = VDV^{-1}$.

Note that $d_i^2 = 1$ for all $i$, and therefore $D^2 = I_n$. Can you compute $A^2$? Can you conclude $A = A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there are three possibilities for its minimal polynomial: $x-1$, $x+1$ and $(x+1)(x-1)$. This means that we have either $A=I$, $A=-I$ or $(A+I)(A-I)=A^2-I=0$. In all three cases, $A^2=I$, therefore $A^{-1}=A$.